# Jelastic intellij plugin not working outdated

Tags: jelastic

Jelastic plugin on
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7139-jelastic-cloud-platform-integration
is not working.
Error message is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/DataKeys
    at com.jelastic.plugin.idea.ui.JelasticTreeCellRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(JelasticTreeCellRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$NodeDimensionsHandler.getNodeDimensions(BasicTreeUI.java:2807)
    at javax.swing.tree.AbstractLayoutCache.getNodeDimensions(AbstractLayoutCache.java:492)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.updatePreferredSize(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1360)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.getPreferredWidth(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1177)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.getMaxNodeWidth(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1008)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.getPreferredWidth(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:309)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.updateCachedPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:1900)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:2003)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTreeUI.java:1991)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:791)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1511)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1500)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1696)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1705)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1631)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:726)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:724)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:723)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1859)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:719)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:668)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
I found this thread on 2013
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206769215-NoClassDefFoundError-in-plugin
It seems plugin needs to update for new api key elements.

Comment: For IntelliJ idea, Ulitmate  2018.3.4 works fine. Could you give more detail about the environment of the user (os, idea version and type)?

Comment: It seems that plugin supports only java based related environments and projects, I can not see python environments on jelastic environment, I added provider for example cloudjiffy.com as Custom host. I can see list on Eclipse but can not see on Intelli J, PyCharm. Do you have any plan to support PHP, Ruby, Python environments?

Comment: We have this point in our backlog, but no exact estimates so far. Thank you.

Comment: Naturally, we will eliminate Jelastic stack for our projects due to lack of support, other PAAS and FAAS options will be considered, in addition, jelastic based paas cloud are too expensive, 1 GB ram and  core is maximum 2 euro/month on IAAS clouds, on your platform is 6-28 euro range.

Comment: It's natural to pay more for a more comprehensive service. For example most Jelastic providers include backups and support, with IaaS you must pay extra for these. Likewise the platform is doing much more for you than only providing the basic infrastructure. You cannot expect to pay the same money for infrastructure + more as you would pay for basic infrastructure.